# How to add on scroll animation in magento 2 using AOS (Animation On Scroll) Jquery?

Tags: magento2, jquery, cms-pages

I have tried to add on **scroll animation** in my Magento 2 cms page. I used [AOS Jquery](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) for that.

I have added the js and CSS file and initialize AOS through cms page but It will shows

> Uncaught TypeError: AOS.init is not a function

Does anyone have an idea how to use AOS in Magento2?

Comment: did u got any solution

Answer (score 1):

As per Vishwas answer, you can do just a little modification in **`requirejs-config.js`** file

```
var config = {
    'map': {
        '*': {
            'mgsaos': 'Vendor_Module/js/aos'
        }
    }
}
```

Then in **`.phtml`** you can call or use it like this:

```
require(['jquery', 'mgsaos'], function($,mgsaos,AOS){
      $(document).ready(function(){
         AOS.init({
           duration: 1200
         });
    });
 });
```

You can use this [**`aos.js`**](https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js) copy it and save it in your custom module **`web/js`** folder.

UPDATE: ANOTHER way is to use external AOS js by including it the **default.xml**

> Create default.xml file inside app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js" src_type="url" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Then you can easily use it in your **phtml** like this:

```
<script>
    AOS.init({
        easing: 'ease-out-back',
        duration: 1200
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: already used this : https://bit.ly/2Dlqreb

Comment: I see, you can try the update in my answer

Comment: still it shows issue

Comment: @user1799722 make sure to run upgrade then redeploy static content

Comment: yes it did same can u check link

Comment: @user1799722 still can't seem to find the aos.js in your website makeu sure it is added to make it work

Answer (score 1):

You may try this, It works for me.

**step 1)**

File: ***app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js***

```
var config = {

map: {
    '*': {
        'mgsaos' :  'Vendor_Module/js/aos'
    }
},
"shim": {
    "mgsaos": ['jquery'],
}
};
```

Step 2) JS and HTML code in your PHTML file.

```
<div data-aos="fade-up"
     data-aos-anchor-placement="center-center" class="aos-item" >
     <div class="aos-item__inner"><h3> AOS</h3></div>
</div>


<div data-aos="fade-up"
     data-aos-anchor-placement="center-center" class="aos-item" >
     <div class="aos-item__inner"><h3> Hello World</h3></div>
</div>





<script type="text/javascript">
requirejs( [ 'require', 'jquery',  'mgsaos' ],
function( require, $, AOS ) {
         AOS.init({
                  duration: 1200,
         });

});
</script>
```

**Note :** I did not use **script type="text/x-magento-init"** 
instead I use script **type="text/javascript"*** to Init AOS.

step 3) Run below commands to remove static files.

```
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
sudo rm -rf var/pub/static/*
sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
sudo rm -rf var/generated
sudo rm -rf var/composer_home
sudo rm -rf var/page_cache
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
```

[image]

Comment: hi can u check what i am missing i did like same still not working :  bit.ly/2Dlqreb

Comment: Hi, AOS is working in your web site but it is not working properly for all divs, maybe due to CSS (or some other JS files). I copy paste your page content in my local and run save init script for AOS and it working fine [please check the screencast https://ufile.io/115fr98s ]. So you may check your CSS for further debugging. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just create `requirejs-config.js` file inside your theme template,

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
```

code for js file,

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
            'mgsaos': "js/aos.min"
        },   
    shim: {
        'aos': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Now you can use inside your template like this,

```
<script>
   require([ 'jquery', 'mgsaos' ], function ($,AOS) {
    AOS.init({
      duration: 1200,
    });
});
</script>
```

Now

```
Remove var folder from root
Remove pub/static folder contents.
Run deploy command,

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Hi have tried but it is not working

Comment: already using it check :  https://bit.ly/2Dlqreb

Comment: please help with what i am missing